# change the settings file items in .Net console application

Tags: c#, .net, settings, application-settings, savechanges

I tried to change some setting witch my console application want to set and use on every execution.

1)added a .settings file named **InputSettings**.

2)added two items with Scope:User.

3)change the code like this:

```
private projAPI.InputSettings settings = new InputSettings();
settings.publishEndDate = DateTime.Now;
settings.Save();
```

It doesn't make any changes in setting file, but everytime I run a project, setting is changed when I trace that line.

Is there any mistake I had?

Comment: You need to provide more information. We don't know how InputSettings works (`projAPI`seems to be a namespace in your project). You might have a look at the code behind `InputSettings.Save()` method.

Answer (score 0):

User settings are stored in a different file. See [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f3e1f68-d19c-4a43-a650-bd4afa9c4593/c-application-settings-where-are-they-stored):

> If you want to get to the path programmatically, you can do it using the Configuration Management API (you need to add a reference to System.Configuration.dll). For example, here is how you can get the local user.config file path:
>
> ```
> Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
> Console.WriteLine("Local user config path: {0}", config.FilePath);
> ```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx) lists a few examples on how to use application and user settings.

For example [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Access the setting and assign it a new value as shown in this example:
>
> ```
> Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.AliceBlue;
> ```
>
> If you want to persist the changes to the settings between application sessions, call the Save method as shown in this example:
>
> ```
> Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
> ```

Comment: and how can I save/ get values in the new path?

Comment: You don't actually need to know where the file is in order to store and retrieve settings. I just wanted to show you that user settings have their own file in the user's AppData folder (in order to have different values for different users).

There are examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx) about how to use the settings. For example: [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried exactly the same as above link. But didnt save setting.